facing Error resolving plugin [id: 'com.facebook.react.settings'] error
I am facing react native Error resolving plugin [id: 'com.facebook.react.settings'] error when i run react native then this error is come.
react-native version : 0.76.0,
java-version : 17,
error log:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Settings file 'D:\tvos-example\TVTest\android\settings.gradle' line: 2

What went wrong:
Error resolving plugin [id: 'com.facebook.react.settings']



java.io.UncheckedIOException: Could not move temporary workspace (D:\tvos-example\TVTest\android.gradle\8.10.2\dependencies-accessors\569c8b261a8a714d7731d5f568e0e5c05babae10-12801969-005d-4b2e-ae5f-74c556171c50) to immutable location (D:\tvos-example\TVTest\android.gradle\8.10.2\dependencies-accessors\569c8b261a8a714d7731d5f568e0e5c05babae10)


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 3s
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
I try lot of things like remove gradle cache file and remove node modules and stuff like that but i can not found any solution. Guys please help me to out this situation.

hey guys, I need your help Please give me solution for this problem Please guys, I am in trouble

Please downgrade react-native version and try again.

Sir I don't want to downgrade the react-native version. Here is any solution because a lot of people use the latest version?.

@react-native/gradle-plugin
Adding it as a devDependency first then try to run your app.

No, sir, still its not working

You encounter the error:
Error resolving plugin [id: 'com.facebook.react.settings']
After creating a new React Native project, follow these steps:

Install dependencies:
npm install

Navigate to the Android folder:
cd android

Clean the Android build cache:


./gradlew clean

Return to the root directory:


cd ..

Build and run the app:


npx react-native run-android
However, despite the error message, your application should still build and run successfully on your device or emulator. The issue seems to be related to a default cache problem in React Native. Running the above steps resolves it.
This worked for me, and I hope it works for you too! 

No brother, it is not work for me, I also tried this but this is not working

I was too getting this error just follow the steps as mentioned on this page then

opened Android Studio gave it some time for indexing and all to finish.
Then executed below command


npm run android

And it somehow got fixed and seems to be working fine everywhere now.

No, Brother, it is not working. Still, an error is coming.

just use this gradle version 8.5, this will solved
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.5-all.zip

